# AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute 'all' Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

This is my full code of Flask application:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/test'

# Order matters: Initialize SQLAlchemy before Marshmallow
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    price = db.Column(db.Float)


class ProductSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    products = Product.all()
    products_schema = ProductSchema(many=true)

    output = products_schema.dump(products).data
    return jsonify(output)
```

As you can see I tried to extract data from `Product` model:

```
products = Product.all()
```

And I have got this error:

```
request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Projects\Dist\backend\index.py", line 27, in hello_world
    products = Product.all()
AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: It's `Product.query.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the use the `.query` attribute to access the *query object*; `.all()` is a method on that object:

```
products = Product.query.all()
```

From the [*Querying Reconds* section](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/queries/#querying-records) of the Flask-SQLAchemy documentation:

> So how do we get data back out of our database? For this purpose Flask-SQLAlchemy provides a `query` attribute on your `Model` class. When you access it you will get back a new query object over all records.  You can then use methods like `filter()` to filter the records before you fire the select with `all()` or `first()`. If you want to go by primary key you can also use `get()`.

`Model.query` is an instance of (a [subclass of](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery)) the SQLAlchemy [`Query` class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query).